# Unhashable type: 'dict' while applying a function with pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I am using requests library to wrap into a function an api:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, json

def foo(text):
    payload = {'key': '00ac1ef82687c7533d54be2e9', 'of': 'json', \
               'nko': text, \
               'woei': 'm', \
               'nvn': 'es'}

    r = requests.get('http://api.example.com/foo', params=payload)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    return data
```

Then, I would like to apply the above function to the following dataframe:

df:

```
    colA
0   lore lipsum dolor done
1   lore lipsum
2   done lore
3   dolor lone lipsum
```

Thus, I tried the following:

```
df['new_col'] = df['colA'].apply(foo)
df
```

However, I got the following exception:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in
>   apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    2287     2288
>   if is_extension_type(self.dtype):
>   -> 2289                 mapped = self._values.map(f)    2290             else:    2291                 values = self.asobject
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py in
>   map(self, mapper)
>       950             return self.from_codes(self._codes.copy(),
>       951                                    categories=new_categories,
>   --> 952                                    ordered=self.ordered)
>       953         except ValueError:
>       954             return np.take(new_categories, self._codes)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py in
>   from_codes(cls, codes, categories, ordered, name)
>       466                 "codes need to be convertible to an arrays of integers")
>       467 
>   --> 468         categories = cls._validate_categories(categories)
>       469 
>       470         if len(codes) and (codes.max() >= len(categories) or codes.min() < -1):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py in
>   _validate_categories(cls, categories, fastpath)
>       571             # categories must be unique
>       572 
>   --> 573             if not categories.is_unique:
>       574                 raise ValueError('Categorical categories must be unique')
>       575
>
> pandas/src/properties.pyx in pandas.lib.cache_readonly.**get**
>   (pandas/lib.c:43685)()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in
>   is_unique(self)    1068     def is_unique(self):    1069         """
>   return if the index has unique values """
>   -> 1070         return self._engine.is_unique    1071     1072     @property
>
> pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.is_unique.**get**
>   (pandas/index.c:4883)()
>
> pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.initialize
>   (pandas/index.c:5828)()
>
> pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations
>   (pandas/hashtable.c:13788)()
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Therefore, my question is how can I apply correctly `foo` function to `df` column?

Comment: The definition of your function `foo()` is not helpful. I replaced its body with `return json.loads("[1,2,3,{\"a\":123}]")` - the error could not be reproduced.

Comment: You can try this: `df[['colA']].apply(foo, axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks for the help @MaxU, your solution worked, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `df['colA'].apply(foo)` is similar to: `foo(df['colA'])` (where `df['colA']` - is a `pandas.Series`), so your function should be able to accept pandas.Series as an argument - if it's not the case and `foo()` can accept only scalar arguments, then we have to call `foo()` for each row:

```
df[['colA']].apply(foo, axis=1)
```

NOTE: `df[['colA']]` - is a DataFrame, as [Series.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) function doesn't have `axis` argument

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... how can I modify my function in order to receive a pandas column as an argument?

Comment: @tumbleweed, you are welcome! Your current implementation already receives the whole column (Series). So it depends on the `http://api.example.com/foo` - is it able to process / accept a list (series) of values?

Comment: the api by default can accept a string (`nko` parameter ), how should I pass correctly the dataframe to the `nko` parameter?.

Comment: @tumbleweed, if `nko` must be a string, then most probably you can't pass the whole column. Alternatively you can try to implement a loop in the `foo()` function and call there `http://api.example.com/foo` in multiple processes for all rows (all values in a column) in order to speed it up.